# VB.NET Zebra Lines

Tags: vb.net

i want to "draw" zebra lines in my form

[image: zebra]

not a table, just lines
black
white
black
white

ican import background image, but I prefer code :)

Comment: Is this a WinForm project?  How is the text displayed?  In a control, or just painted to the surface of the form?

Comment: We cannot answer your question beacuse you are not telling us what you are doing. What are you talking about? A winForms control a report of some kind a gridview, ASP.NET or WinForms or WPF or anything else? What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes, WinForm  i want zebra lines in the background of the project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
TextBox1.Text = 80
        If IsNumeric(TextBox1.Text) Then
            Dim color As Integer = 1
            Dim top As Integer = 10
            Dim LineNum As Integer = Integer.Parse(TextBox1.Text)
            For i = 0 To LineNum
                Dim line As New Panel
                line.Width = 300
                line.Height = 40

                If color = 1 Then
                    color = 0
                    line.BackColor = Drawing.Color.Black
                Else
                    color = 1
                    line.BackColor = Drawing.Color.White
                End If
                top = top + 40
                line.Top = top
                Me.Controls.Add(line)

            Next

        End If
```

;)

Answer (score 0):

Zebra for datagridview VB.NET

```
 DataGridView1.GridColor = Color.Blue
 DataGridView1.DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black 
 DataGridView1.RowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red
 DataGridView1.AlternatingRowsDefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Yellow
 DataGridView1.GridColor = Color.Silver
```